# Question is on hold

Tags: discussion

My question was put on hold because it is unclear. I thought it could happen because I have little familiarity with the subject, probably use the wrong terminology etc. Could you tell me what is unclear? Perhaps I was using the wrong forum?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81128/using-cloud-oracle-server-in-net-application-asp-net-web-site

I need to use a website build using Microsoft technology to connect to an Oracle database that would reside in a cloud (Amazon, Azure, ....). I could not find how to connect them (I presume the connection line I would use for the physical server won't work for the cloud-based server). I do not know how to make it clearer, maybe you could tell me what I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: I think your question is too chatty and vague - if you ask a single, specific question you may find it is better received.